# Regex matching open or closed Python string

Tags: python, regex

I'd like find the contents of all Python strings in source code as that code is being typed. I assume the string is contained within a single line, but it might not be closed yet.

Right now I have

```
for m in re.finditer('''(?P<open>(?:""")|"|(?:''\')|')(?:((?P<closed>.*?)(?P=open))|(?P<unclosed>.*))''', 'as"df'):
    i = 3 if m.group(3) else 4
    print m.group(i)
```

But I'd love to have a predictable match group to search on. Something like

```
re.finditer('''(?P<open>(?:""")|"|(?:''\')|')(.*?)(?P=open)''', line)
```

is nicer because the contents of the string literal will always be in match group (but this one doesn't match strings that aren't yet closed).

Edit: I'm fine with multiline matches, I just mean to make the problem simpler by excluding them from being in the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
(?s)('''|"""|'|")((?:(?=([^"'\\]+|\\.|(?!\1)["']))\3)*)\1?
```

The quote is captured in group 1, a backreference is used at the end to close the string `\1`.

`[^"'\\]+ | \\. | (?!\1)["']` describes allowed content:

```
[^"'\\]+   # all that is not a quote or a backslash
\\.        # an escaped character
(?!\1)["'] # a quote that is not the captured quote
```

Then, to repeat these elements without risking a [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), I emulate an [atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) with this trick:
`(?>subpattern)*` => `(?:(?=(subpattern))\1)*`

Note: If you want to forbid multiline matches, you only need to change the allowed content to
`[^"'\r\n\\]+ | \\. | (?!\1)["']` and to remove the `(?s)` modifier.

[EDIT]

If you want to match a backslash at the end of the string (example: `text = r'''abc def ghi\`), you need to change the pattern to:

multiline mode:

```
(?m)('''|"""|'|")((?:(?=([^"'\r\n\\]+|\\(?:.|$)|(?!\1)["']))\3)*)\1?
```

singleline mode:

```
(?s)('''|"""|'|")((?:(?=([^"'\\]+|\\(?:.|$)|(?!\1)["']))\3)*)\1?
```

Comment: This doesn't match a string that is not closed yet. Question specifically says `but it might not be closed yet.`

Comment: @KassymDorsel: exact, now it does. Thanks

Comment: Even with the great explanation here, I had trouble understanding this. https://www.debuggex.com/i/2kIDbiqopXOeVFbs.png helped me.

Comment: @Thomas:It isn't an easy pattern, in particular the trick that use the fact that the content of a lookahead is naturaly atomic.

Comment: @Thomas: a little edit, if you want to match a backslash at the end of the string or line.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
^("""|'''|"|')((?!\\").*?)(?:(?<!\\)\1$|$)
```

I'm not exactly sure as to the behaviour you would like when it comes down strings that are syntactically wrong, when you have two double quotes before you get to three (at the start and end). But from what I understand this should do the job.

Use the second match group in your code.

Comment: This has multiple match groups I have to check, like my top example.

Comment: Oh, overlooked that part. Updated answer.